# Using ACE syntax highligher for Flask-Admin field override

Tags: javascript, python, flask, syntax-highlighting

Following the following tip for overriding flask-admin fields, I am trying to get the Ace syntax highlighter working.

https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#wysiwig-text-fields

The idea is to get sql server syntax highlighting on the wtforms text area.

This attempt is not working, not sure what else to include in the extra js?

```
class ACETextAreaWidget(TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):

        if kwargs.get('class'):
            kwargs['class'] += ' ace'
        else:
            kwargs.setdefault('class', 'ace')

        return super(ACETextAreaWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)

class ACETextAreaField(TextAreaField):
    widget = ACETextAreaWidget()


class ControlAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    #extra_js = ['//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.0/standard/ckeditor.js']
    extra_js = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ace.js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/mode-sqlserver.js']
```

Comment: What errors or warnings are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are actually using the `ACETextAreaWidget`. In the linked code they put it in what is `ControlAdmin` in the code above. You might just need to add these lines to `ControlAdmin`:

```
form_overrides = {
    'body': ACETextAreaWidget
}
```